# Change the color of one word in a phrase using label, libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Is it possible to change the colour of one word in a 
phrase using Label in libgdx, my idea is on my dialog box some importante words like important places, or names have a different color than the rest of the text to make them stand out.

Comment: I found this [link](https://github.com/rafaskb/typing-label) its working but I having problems with fonts

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't need to use any third party artifact, LibGDX has built in API for your requirement. You can use [color markup language](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Color-Markup-Language), that Label supports as well.

Enable markupEnabled on the BitmapFont

```
font.getData().markupEnabled = true;
```

---

I've some code

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private Stage stage;
    private BitmapFont bitmapFont;

    @Override
    public void create () {

        stage=new Stage();
        bitmapFont=new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("Roboto-Medium_24.fnt"));
        bitmapFont.getData().markupEnabled=true;
        bitmapFont.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

        Label label=new Label("Welcome to [BLUE]LibGDX, []Game development framework \n" +
                "\nPublish your games on [GREEN]Windows,[] [#00FFFF]Mac, []Linux, [#FFFF00]Android,[] [BLACK]iOS,[] BlackBerry and HTML5, all with the same code base. ",new Label.LabelStyle(bitmapFont, Color.WHITE));
        label.setPosition(20,340);
        label.setWrap(true);
        label.setWidth(500);
        stage.addActor(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        stage.dispose();
        bitmapFont.dispose();
    }
}
```

Output :

[image]